# Magento addFieldToFilter on collection - how do to get a AND where clause

Tags: sql, magento

I have the following code to load a custom collection:

```
echo Mage::getModel("ibi/despatchqueues")
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter(
    array(
        'can_sync',
        'is_synced'
    ),
    array(
        array('eq' => 1), // can_sync  = 1
        array('eq' => 0), // is_synced = 0
    )
)
->getSelect();
```

This produces the following SQL Query:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `despatchqueues` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (((can_sync = 1) or (is_synced = 0)))
```

How do I change my `addFieldToFilter` so that the resulting query will look like this:

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `despatchqueues` AS `main_table` 
WHERE (((can_sync = 1) and (is_synced = 0)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try like this

```
 echo Mage::getModel("ibi/despatchqueues")
->getCollection()
->addFieldToFilter('can_sync', array('eq' => 1))
->addFieldToFilter('is_synced', array('eq' => 0))
->getSelect();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Oh I see how it works. Each `addFieldToFilter` acts as an `AND` when there is more than one. Thanks for that.